# ConstraintLayout's blueprint does not match the final design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

As I have updated to `Android Studio 2.2`, I tried new `ConstraintLayout` to create a simple Activity. Surprisingly, `alpha 8` (currently the most up-to-date) is really buggy, causing multiple resets in the blueprint stage.

The main problem is that all items that I have added through Blueprint are not constrained in the Design tab:

[Design and Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytnhq.png)

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.openejb:openejb-telnet:3.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
}
```

I do remember unchecking or checking some checkmark when creating new Empty Activity. Does it have to do with that?

Activity class extends `Activity`.

Please help me get rid of bugs of new layout constructor.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_telnet"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xx.xxx.xxxx.TelnetActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="IP:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_IP"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:inputType="text|textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_IP"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_IP" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="Port:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_port"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_IP"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_IP"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_port"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_port"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/et_IP"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="Connect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_connect"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_port"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:onClick="connect (TelnetActivity)"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Status:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_connect"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Disconnected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/et_port"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Send msg:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_sendMsg"
        android:layout_width="180dp" android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/et_port"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Response:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_response"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_status"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"/>
    <Button
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_sendMsg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_sendMsg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_sendMsg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/et_port" android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44" android:onClick="sendMsg (TelnetActivity)"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: Restarting Android Studio helped with getting all the elements on the right places, until I moved any of them. After that - everything collapses again.

Comment: Post your code so we can debug this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you updated from alpha7 to alpha8 (which is probably the case if you downloaded Android Studio 2.2), you may need to rebuild your project and/or do File->Invalidate Caches in Studio -- though restarting Studio should have been enough. Tell me if that works for you.

Also; on which environment are you running? (Windows, Mac, Linux, which JVM...)

Comment: I did not update from alpha 7, alpha 8 was the first release for me. I am using Mac OS X 10.11.6. File->Invalidate Caches in Studio did the trick so far :)  PS: I watched your presentation about ConstraintLayout just yday!! That is sooo dope that YOU answered!

Comment: Glad it helped!